# Eclipse clean removes my config file

Tags: eclipse, build, configuration-files

In my Eclipse **Java Build Path**, I set **Source Output Folders** to:

> WEB-INF/classes

and I put the config file `globals.conf` in this folder.

When I run **Project - Clean**, my config file `globals.conf` is gone

How can I keep my config file when I run **Clean**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`globals.conf` should be putted under source folder, not source output folder.

Eclipse will copy all resource files(not *.java) in source folder into output folder.